# Python Data Structure for keeping Count in Tuples?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a list of people objects like this...

```
class person:
    monthlyTaskCount = [] 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

bob = person("Bob Smith")
sam = person("Sam Jones")
amy = person("Amy Owen")

people = [bob,sam,amy]
```

And I'm comparing to a list of tasks to count and keep track of how many tasks they performed a month...

```
for x in taskList: #contains x.personName, x.taskName, x.monthPerformed
    for p in people:
         if x.personName == p.name:
            #append to p.monthlyTaskCount in some way
```

I'm stuck because I can't visualise an appropriate way to keep track of month-by-month data and end up with something like this for p.amy.monthlyTaskCount...

```
[11/2018:23, 12/2018:12, 1/2019:19, 2/2019:34]
```

(showing 23 tasks completed for Nov 2018 etc)

I'm just lost in terms of finding an elegant way to store data in this format - e.g. simply appending values to a list would result in duplicate entries per month which I'd then have to clean-up afterwards so I'm hoping there's a data structure someone could recommend that would solve the problem.

Comment: Do you just want [a `set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)? Maybe a `collections.defaultdict(set)` if you want a mapping from keys to sets of values? Or `collections.Counter` if you're just counting things?

Comment: Without the input and any explanation we can not assert what is wrong with your output.

Comment: Also just to add, you might want to instantiate the list within `__init__` as shared data involving mutable objects might have surprising effects. You can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this problem would be a lot easier to solve if you were using dictionaries to store more of your data. For instance, rather than putting the `people` in a list, but them in a dictionary keyed by their name, and you can immediately look up the appropriate `person` instance rather than needing to iterate through the list each time.

Similarly, the per-month count should probably be another dictionary, or maybe a dictionary subtype like `collections.Counter` (which is specifically designed for counting things).

There's another issue with how you're setting `monthlyTaskCount` in your class: All the instances will share the same list, since it's being created as a class variable. You should probably move its creation into the `__init__` method so each `person` gets their own copy.

Anyway, here's my suggestion:

```
import collections

class person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        monthlyTaskCount = collections.Counter()

bob = person("Bob Smith")
sam = person("Sam Jones")
amy = person("Amy Owen")

people = {p.name: p for p in [bob, sam, amy]}
```

With the improved data structures, your bookkeeping becomes easy:

```
for x in taskList: #contains x.personName, x.taskName, x.monthPerformed
    people[x.personName].monthlyTaskCount[x.monthPerformed] += 1
```